# How can I fix the error 'Is the MGS running?' when I try to mount FSx for lustre in Vagrant ( Virtualbox, Centos 7 )

Tags: virtualbox, aws, vagrant, lustre

I am running openVPN gateway to an AWS VPC. I can normally mount AWS FSx for Lustre on my bare metal CENTOS7 machine using a command like this

```
sudo mount -t lustre -o noatime,flock 10.1.1.90@tcp:/fsx /fsx
```

However if I try to do the same thing in a vagrant CENTOS 7 box on the same network, I will encounter this apparent networking related error:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo mount -t lustre -o noatime,flock 10.1.1.90@tcp:/fsx /fsx
mount.lustre: mount 10.1.1.90@tcp:/fsx at /fsx failed: Input/output error
Is the MGS running?
```

The vagrant box has no problem mounting NFS shares from the same AWS subnet, so this is a mystery to me.  Being able to get it working in the vagrant image matters even though I can get it to work on bare metal because we use the vagrant environment for testing.

I can also share an example vagrant file that I can replicate the problem with.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "centos/7"
    config.vagrant.plugins = ['vagrant-vbguest', 'vagrant-disksize', 'vagrant-reload']
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.gui = true
        v.memory = 2048
        v.cpus = 2
        
    end
    config.disksize.size = "65000MB"
    config.vm.network "public_network", use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo yum update -y"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo yum install wget -y"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo wget https://fsx-lustre-client-repo-public-keys.s3.amazonaws.com/fsx-rpm-public-key.asc -O /tmp/fsx-rpm-public-key.asc"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo rpm --import /tmp/fsx-rpm-public-key.asc"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo wget https://fsx-lustre-client-repo.s3.amazonaws.com/el/7/fsx-lustre-client.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/aws-fsx.repo"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo yum install -y kmod-lustre-client lustre-client"
    config.vm.provision :reload
end
```